# How can check whether my hash password store in the right way in database?

Tags: php, laravel

I created a simple multiauth in Laravel (admin, user). They both authorize the user and admin login normally.

Yesterday, when I open the admin login page and try to login, it shows me

> These credentials do not match our records.

I said OK maybe I wrote the incorrect password. I made a new account via `Seed` like this:

```
AdminSeeder.php

public function run()
{
    Admin::create([
        'name'=>'admin',
        'email'=>'admin@gmail.com',
        'password'=> Hash::make('123456'),
    ]);
}
```

I go again and try to login with the correct credentials, but I got the same error message. Then I tried to make a new user via `Tinker`, to verify if there is an error in my `Seed`. I create new one and then try to login but I get the same error.

In my admin panel I created a page for admin to add more than one admin! Again I create a new admin account from my page and login, `here it works!` with the same `HASH` function in seed!

Next, I tried to create a new Laravel project and just move my important files to new one, again the same thing with the new one!

I really don't know what's going on! I think there is a problem in hash password when I create a new account via `Seed` and `Tinker`!

Comment: You should really check if somewhere you're not hashing he password input twice, which might just cause the problem.

Comment: I have this function in Admin model!    public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
    }
is it possible this make this error!!

Comment: Yes, exactly! Because you're once giving an already hashed value as `$value` to your setter and then once again hasing it in the setter.

Comment: Oh God!!!  let me try!

Comment: @D.Petrov yessssssssss it works!!!!!! thank you so much bro!

Comment: Glad to help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out, password was getting hashed twice due to an extensive custom password setter in the Admin model. Issue was resolved by removing the mentioned setter.